# Using a verb after ‘is' or verb after 'is'

Tags: grammar

I would like to know why there are two verbs in the following sentence:

> All I **watch is** the weather.

Why do we use '**is**' after '**watch**' in this sentence? It seems strange that there are two verbs.

If anyone could explain this sentence structure I would be grateful.

Another example would be:

> All you **need is love**.

Comment: The first one is part of a subject clause "All (that) I watch...". the main verb is "is".

Answer (score -1):

There is only one verb, **is**:

> All I watch **is** the weather.

In this case the word *watch* is used as a noun. It is the same with *All you need is love*, where *love* is a noun.

This is called nominalisation, where a noun phrase is generated from another word class, usually a verb. In other words, the process of nominalisation turns verbs (actions or events) into nouns (things, concepts or people).